# Why am I unable to add an Alias to my Vhost via the Puppet Apache Module?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, puppet

Here is the snippet from my manifest:

```
  apache::vhost { 'default-http':
    port     => 80,
    serveraliases => ['example.test.com', 'example2.test.com',],
    docroot  => '/var/www/html',
    rewrites => [
      {
        comment      => 'Bounce to https',
        rewrite_cond => ['"%{SERVER_PROTOCOL}"  "!^HTTP$"'],
        rewrite_rule => ['"^/?(.*)" "https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1" [R=permanent,L]'],
      }
    ],
  }
```

As you can see in the following config, the aliases are nowhere to be found:

```
# Vhost template in module puppetlabs-apache
# Managed by Puppet
# ************************************

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default-http

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

  ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/html

  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/default-http_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/default-http_access.log" combined
  ## Rewrite rules
  RewriteEngine On

  #Bounce to https
  RewriteCond "%{SERVER_PROTOCOL}"  "!^HTTP$"
  RewriteRule "^/?(.*)" "https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1" [R=permanent,L]
```

I assume there is something wrong with my serveraliases line, as everything else shows up in the config other than that line.  Unfortunately I do not see any errors in the logs to guide me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [arrays](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/style_guide.html#arrays-and-hashes), it's recommended in
The Puppet Language Style Guide that...

> To increase readability of arrays and hashes, it is almost always
>   beneficial to break up the elements on separate lines.
>
> Use a single line only if that results in overall better readability
>   of the construct where it appears, such as when it is very short. When
>   breaking arrays and hashes, they should have:
>
> - Each element on its on line,
> - Each new element line indented one level,
> - First and last lines used only for the syntax of that data type.

The 
example from [Configuring virtual hosts](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/README.md#configuring-virtual-hosts) looks like this:

```
apache::vhost { 'aliases.example.com':
  serveraliases => [
    'aliases.example.org',
    'aliases.example.net',
  ],
  port          => '80',
  docroot       => '/var/www/aliases',
}
```

The only thing different in your configuration is that you don't have spaces between `[ '` and `', ],`. That would have been automatically avoided by using the best practices for formatting arrays.

Comment: This fixed it.. I didn't think it would, as it says "recommended for readability".  Thanks